# Where is the setting that disallows duplicate command history?

Tags: bash, command-history

Let's say I type the following sequence of commands:

```
$ cd
$ ls
$ ls
```

When I go back in history by pressing <kbd>up</kbd> twice, I end up with `cd`, instead of `ls`.

I've noticed this isn't always the case, so it likely is some bash setting somewhere. Which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The is controlled by the `HISTCONTROL` variable.  If is contains `ignoredups`, then duplicate commands will not be saved in the history.  Without this string, they will be saved.  This would be normally set in `.profile` or `.bashrc`, using something like

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

Other values that can be used in HISTCONTROL (multiple can be used, separated by `:`)

- *ignorespace* any commands starting with a space are not added to the history
- *erasedups* duplicate commands are erased from the history, so the history only contains the latest command
- *ignoreboth* identical to `ignoredups:ignorespace`

Answer (score 1):

`HISCONTROL=ignoredups`

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables