# Bash history: "ignoredups" and "erasedups" setting conflict with common history across sessions

Tags: bash, command-history

First of all, this is not a duplicate of any existing threads on SE. I have read these two threads ([1st](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/better-bash-history), [2nd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6585/where-is-the-setting-that-disallows-duplicate-command-history)) on better bash history, but none of the answers work - - I am on Fedora 15 by the way.

I added the following to the `.bashrc` file in the user directory (/home/aahan/), and it doesn't work. Anyone has a clue?

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
HISTSIZE=1000                     # custom history size
HISTFILESIZE=100000                 # custom history file size
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"  # Save and reload the history after each command finishes
```

Okay this is what I want with the bash history (priority):

- don't store duplicates, erase any existing ones
- immediately share history with all open terminals
- always append history, not overwrite it
- store multi-line commands as a single command (which is off by default)
- what's the default History size and history file size?

Comment: bump! anyone? Nothing works. Could this be a problem with Fedora 15 (with Gnome 3 and running on a Windows host virtual machine)?

Comment: Please don't "bump" posts here. If they aren't getting answered you need to ask more clearly, include the right bits of context clues, or something. If you need attention on your posts you can issue bounties that help get more people paying them more attention.

Comment: Are you sure you are even using bash? (`echo $SHELL`). Do the settings work if you run them manually from your open shell? Obviously since they do work for so many others the settings are right, you are just implementing them wrong. And no Fedora15/Gnome3/being a virtual machine have little to do with the actual function of `bash`.

Comment: @Caleb, first sorry about bumping the post. Also, I tried my best to be very clear. No, I haven't issued them in the shell. I just copy-pasted them into `.bashrc` file. Is that wrong? Can you add an "answer" to this post with the actual shell commands? (please bear with my noob-ity.)

Comment: Everything you write in scripts or `.bashrc` ARE actual shell commands. Scripts are just series of shell commands. Also the edit you recently made removing the `export` bit was a bad idea, that should be kept.

Comment: So for example, is this `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups` a command that should be implemented in shell? If so, I think I tried that multiple times. No changes have taken place in the `.bashrc` file. (isn't that where I should be looking?)

Comment: Is using zsh an option? Many bash problems can be solved by switching to zsh. History management is one of the areas where zsh is smarter.

Comment: @Gilles is zsh just like the default terminal (shell)? I mean the commands and stuff? (Checking it out already!)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is actually a really interesting behavior and I confess I have greatly underestimated the question at the beginning.  But first the facts:

#### 1. What works

The functionality can be achieved in several ways, though each works a bit differently. Note that, in each case, to have the history "transferred" to another terminal (updated), one has to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the terminal, where he/she wants to retrieve the history.

- option 1:

  ```
   shopt -s histappend
   HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
   PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
  ```

This has two drawbacks:

1. At login (opening a terminal), the last command from the history file is read twice into the current terminal's history buffer;
2. The buffers of different terminals do not stay in sync with the history file.

- option 2:

  ```
   HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
   PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
  ```

(Yes, no need for `shopt -s histappend` and yes, it *has to be* `history -c` in the middle of `PROMPT_COMMAND`)
This version has  also two important drawbacks:

1. The history file has to be initialized. It has to contain *at least one non-empty line* (can be anything).
2. The `history` command can give false output - see below.

**[Edit]**
*"And the winner is..."*

- **option 3:**

  ```
   HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
   shopt -s histappend
   PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
  ```

This is as far as it gets. It is the *only* option to have both `erasedups` and common history working simultaneously.
**This** is probably the *final solution* to all your problems, Aahan.

---

#### 2. Why does *option 2* not seem to work (or: *what really* doesn't work as expected)?

As I mentioned, each of the above solutions works differently. But **the most misleading interpretation of how the settings work comes from analysing the output of `history` command**.  In many cases, the command can give **false** output. Why? Because **it is executed *before* the sequence of other `history` commands contained in the `PROMPT_COMMAND`!** However, when using the second or third option, one can monitor the changes of `.bash_history` contents  (using `watch -n1 "tail -n20 .bash_history"` for example) and see what the real history is.

#### 3. Why *option 3* is so complicated?

It all lies in the way `erasedups` works. As the bash manual states,  *"(...) `erasedups` causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from  the history list before that line is saved"*. So this is really what the OP wanted *(and not just, as I previously thought, to have no duplicates appearing **in sequence**)*. Here's why each of the `history -.` commands either has to or can not be in the `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

- `history -n`  **has** to be there before `history -w` to read from `.bash_history` the commands saved from any other terminal,
- `history -w` **has** to be there in order to save the new history to the file after bash has checked if the command was a duplicate,
- `history -a` **must not** be placed there instead of `history -w`, because it will add to the file any new command, regardless of whether it was checked as a duplicate.
- `history -c` is also **needed** because it prevents trashing the history buffer after each command,
- and finally, `history -r` is **needed** to restore the history buffer from file, thus finally making the history shared across terminal sessions.

Be aware that this solution will mess up the history order by putting all history from other terminals in front of the newest command entered in the current terminal. It also does not delete duplicate lines already in the history file unless you enter that command again.

Comment: Actually, the history sharing among terminals is working flawlessly for me. But I can't prevent history duplication. That's the only issue ATM.

Comment: +1 for "But the most misleading interpretation of how the settings work comes from analysing the output of history command." I think this is the core of the OP's issue. Excellent deduction.

Comment: Have you read the whole explanation and tested by `tail -f  .bash_history`? This is much more complicated than it seems. See also my comment under your own answer.

Comment: yes, I tried `$ tail -f .bash_history` and it listed the commands history (but without IDs - - i.e., unlike `$ history`). Like I said, I am (still) unable to prevent duplication. Does your above answer in a way imply that preventing history duplication is not possible? You gotta [see this](http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/8/22019292657-orig.jpg) as well.

Comment: I finally saw your point. By 'duplicates' you meant something else than myself. I only focused at *sequences of the same command*. Updated my answer - see "option 3". Also, for your case, to test how the history works you should actually use `watch "tail -n 20 .bash_history"` instead of the `tail -f .bash_history`.

Comment: You might also find the following question and it's answer is to be very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338285/prevent-duplicates-from-being-saved-in-bash-history#answer-7449399

Comment: Option 3 just wiped out all of my 100,000 lines of history :( (bash 3.2.25(1)-release)

Comment: *`history -c` is also needed because it prevents trashing the history buffer after each command* Why does this trashing occurs?

Comment: Also note that you may want to check that the value of `$PROMPT_COMMAND` doesn't already contain `history` commands so you don't end up reading and writing it dozens of times per `<CR>` at the prompt.

Comment: Your solution 3 actually does not work.  It's extremely buggy and dependent on the order that users hit enter in different terminals.  It will often result in lost commands, especially when switching back and forth between terminals.  Source: tried it out.

Comment: In my case I do NOT want to immediately share history, just converge on close while avoiding history loss (such as on termination without clean exit).  I settled on adding `history -a` to the prompt for memory safety, and putting option 3's sequence in a trap function (`trap deduphistory EXIT`).

Comment: Additionally, this sequence in the function will remove reliance on adequately sized `HISTSIZE`: `cat ~/.bash_history | nl | sort -k 2 | tac | uniq -f 1 | sort -n | cut -f 2 > ~/.bash_history_new; mv ~/.bash_history_new ~/.bash_history`.  (In this case `history` commands are not used at all.)

Comment: Option 2 seems to work just fine.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz, if I don't care at all about duplicated entries in my history file, would you say [this answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309087/154671) is correct in its recomendation? Essentially, the advice given uses `history -a;` instead of `history -n; history -w;`.

Comment: @HonoredMule Would you care putting the "trap" idea into an answer?

Comment: Done (plus a few more characters).

Comment: The above comment about using `tgrap dedupe_history EXIT` is the same solution I settled on. Seems less wasteful and susceptible to races than reading/writing my 10,000 line history files on every prompt. Has been working well for me for years now. My own dedupe function reads `tac < ~/.bash_history | awk '!a[$0]++' | tac >/tmp/deduped && mv -f /tmp/deduped ~/.bash_history` (Otherwise this answer is BRILLIANT though, and enhanced my understanding no end!)

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost When you enter a command, it is appended to the history list and that list is written to the file. Enter a different command, and any new line added to the file will be appended to the history list with `history -n`, in this case the first command we entered. So you would have a duplicate of that first command in the history list since `history -n` doesn't remove duplicates. `history -c; history -r` syncs the list with the file, making everything in the file 'read',  and preventing `history -n` from putting it into the list.

Comment: I will say two things about the solution: 1. The history of a session is only updated after you have input a command. 2. Your history file size can't be larger than your history size since the file will always be written with what is in the list.

Comment: Actually, one last thing: `history -w` will not clear duplicates before writing to the file. The check for duplicates happens on a command when you type it. And it is only checked against commands in the list, not the file. You can test this by adding duplicate lines at the end of your `.bash_history` with a text editor, then opening bash and running `history -c; history -r; history -w; history`. So `history -a` just adds to the file any new thing you've written regardless of whether it was a duplicate. [My sane solution.](https://gist.github.com/tonijarjour/2d354aad386b0232efe81ba462c79b29)

Comment: @ToniJarjour your "sane solution" is now 404. I guess that's why they try to get peeps to create the content in stack exchange. Would have liked to see your solution.

Comment: @NeilG I have an answer on this question, just updated it.

Comment: Thanks @ToniJarjour I'm trying it now.

Answer (score 10):

In your prompt command, you are using the `-c` switch. From `man bash`:

> **-c**   Clear the history list by deleting all the entries

To share your history with all open terminals, you can use `-n`:

> **-n**   Read the history lines not already read from the history file into  the  current  history list.   These  are  lines appended to the history file since the beginning of the current bash session.

The default size is also in the manual:

> HISTSIZE
>               The number of commands to remember in the command history  (see  HISTORY  below). The  default value is 500.

To save multi-line commands:

> The **cmdhist** shell option, if enabled, causes the shell to attempt to save each line of a multi-line command in  the  same  history entry, adding semicolons where necessary to preserve syntactic correctness.  The **lithist** shell option causes the shell to save the command with embedded newlines instead of semicolons.

Also, you shouldn't preface HIST* commands with `export` — they are bash-only variables not environmental variables: `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups` is sufficient.

Comment: So, this `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` is correct? Also, do you know how I can make the history file store multi-line commands as a single command (which is off by default)??

Comment: Yes. As per the man page quoted above, `shopt -s cmdhist` will save multi-lines.

Comment: okay, I tried 'em all. Looks like `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups` is not working. I also tried having just that in the `.bashrc` file (among custom functions). Any idea what could be wrong? I am using Fedora 15 on a virtual machine - - Windows 7 host.

Comment: Make sure there is nothing in the other startup files, like `/etc/bashrc`, `.bash_profile` etc that is overriding it.

Comment: I dont see any issues with the `.bash_profile` file. As for the content in `/etc/bashrc` I put it here, please take a look - http://pastebin.com/Uae6sE6s

Comment: **EDIT:** Also, Is all this in C language? How are you able to interpret these files?

Comment: Do you have a `.bash_history`? Is it writeable? Otherwise, I'd go back to basics and remove everything and add the commands one at a time and then test.

Comment: Yes. That is how I am testing. I cleared .bash_history file and then tested. What happens is, it works when I open the terminal for the first time and issue commands. Once I close the terminal and open it once again, the commands are duplicated. Looks like they are being considered as different terminals.

Comment: More generally, you don't need to export any variables you set in ~/.bashrc unless you need to make them visible to programs other than bash, since sub-shells will execute ~/.bashrc and perform the same setup for themselves.

Answer (score 10):

Using a combination of @rozcietrzewiacz's option 3 with an exit trap will enable terminals that maintain their own independent history sessions which converge on close.  It even seems to work well with multiple sessions across different machines sharing a remote home directory.

```
export HISTSIZE=5000
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
function historymerge {
    history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r;
}
trap historymerge EXIT
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

- The `historymerge` function loads out-of-session lines from the history file, combines them with session history, writes out a new history file with deduplication (thus squashing any previously appended duplicate lines), and reloads history.
- Keeping `history -a` in the prompt minimizes potential for losing history, as it updates the history file without deduplication on every command.
- Finally, the trap triggers `historymerge` on session close for an up-to-date clean history file with the most recently closed session's commands bubbled to the end of the file (I think).

With this, each terminal session will have its own independent history starting from launch.  I find that more useful as I tend to have different terminals open for different tasks (thus am wanting to repeat different commands in each).  It's also mercifully simpler than making sense of multiple terminals constantly trying to re-sync their *ordered* history in distributed fashion (though you can still do that deliberately using the `historymerge` function with select sessions or all of them).

Note that you'll want your size limits to be large enough to hold the desired history length *plus* the volume of non-deduplicated lines which may be added by all concurrently active sessions.  5000 is sufficient for me largely thanks to the extensive use of `HISTIGNORE` to filter out spammy low-value commands.

Comment: Your `historymerge` does not dedup history for me. At least not the old one.

Comment: If only using `historymerge` with a `trap`, then a useful HISTSIZE hack would be to `export HISTSIZE=$(wc -l "$HISTFILE")`

Answer (score 8):

This is what I came up with and I am happy with it so far…

```
alias hfix='history -n && history | sort -k2 -k1nr | uniq -f1 | sort -n | cut -c8- > ~/.tmp$$ && history -c && history -r ~/.tmp$$ && history -w && rm ~/.tmp$$'  
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace  
shopt -s histappend  
shopt -s extglob  
HISTSIZE=1000  
HISTFILESIZE=2000  
export HISTIGNORE="!(+(*\ *))"  
PROMPT_COMMAND="hfix; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

NOTES:

- Yes, it is complicated... but, it removes all duplicates and yet preserves chronology within each terminal!
- My `HISTIGNORE` ignores all commands that don't have arguments. This may not be desirable by some folks and can be left out.

Comment: Wouldn't the HISTIGNORE pattern work just as well without the `+()` expression? It was really weird to see a regex that ENDS with a 'one or more of X' - that is only useful when you want to continue the expression 'and then Y'.

Comment: Of note: It doesn't take into account nor is compatible with `HISTTIMEFORMAT`

Answer (score 2):

In your `.bashrc` first add:

```
HISTCONTROL='erasedups'
```

Then add the following history cleaning helper function (it removes duplicates):

```
clean_bash_history_file() {
  bash_history_file=$(mktemp "$USER"_bash_historyXXXXXX)
  awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0]++; next; }; ++b[$0] == a[$0]' \
      "$HOME/.bash_history" "$HOME/.bash_history" > "$bash_history_file"
  mv "$bash_history_file" "$HOME/.bash_history"
  unset bash_history_file
}
```

Then make the following history update function:

```
update_history() {   
    history -a
    clean_bash_history_file
    history -c
    history -r
}
```

Finally, add

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_history
```

This will keep the correct history order, and it will remove all duplicates, guaranteed.

It also allows `HISTFILESIZE` to be larger than `HISTSIZE`. Just make sure `shopt -s histappend` is also in your `.bashrc`

Comment: I like this one @ToniJarjour , I'm not exactly sure why but it seems more "sane" as you say. It's pretty clear what it's doing. I'm just trying to update it to handle different bash history's in different locations. I'm trying to implement a different bash history for each of my Tmux sessions. I `source` an "activate" script in the local environment every time I open a shell so I can easily `export` a different `HISTFILE` location in the local environment every time.

Comment: To work with different history files defined by `$HISTFILE` I think this update to the second line of the history clean function will do it. This should also be an improvement for those keeping their bash history somewhere other than the default:

`awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1]++; next; }; ++b[$0] == a[$0]' "$HISTFILE" "$HISTFILE" > "$bash_history_file"`

Comment: Nope. Screws up the bash history, I think because you may have not considered time stamps, but after removing time stamps only records "exit" in the history. Not working.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by changing your `awk` line to: `tail -r $HISTFILE | cat -n | sort -k2 -k1n | uniq -f1 | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f2- | tail -r > $bash_history_file`, where `$HISTFILE` can be used instead of `$HOME/.bash_history`. I got the line to eliminate duplicates while retaining order from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194780/remove-duplicate-lines-while-keeping-the-order-of-the-lines and just reversed it fore and aft in order to preserve the most recent occurrence of duplicates instead of the first occurrence. Now works for me.

Comment: Bash doesnt have `tail -r`, but `tac` works. `tac $HISTFILE | cat -n | sort -k2 -k1n | uniq -f1 | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f2- | tac`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because you forget about:

> ```
>  -n   read all history lines not already read from the history file
>       and append them to the history list
> ```

But it seems `history -n` is just buggy when `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` is in effect.

Lets experiment:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND=
$ export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
$ export HISTFILE=~/.bash_myhistory
$ HISTIGNORE='history:history -w'
$ history -c
$ history -w
```

Here we turn on dups erasing, switch history to custom file, clear the history. After all commands complete we have empty history file and one command at current history.

```
$ history
$ cat ~/.bash_myhistory
$ history
$ 1  [2019-06-17 14:57:19] cat ~/.bash_myhistory
```

Open second terminal and run those six command too. After that:

```
$ echo "X"
$ echo "Y"
$ history -w
$ history
  1  [2019-06-17 15:00:21] echo "X"
  2  [2019-06-17 15:00:23] echo "Y"
```

Now your current history has two commands and history file has:

```
#1560772821
echo "X"
#1560772823
echo "Y"
```

Back to first terminal:

```
$ history -n
$ history
1  [2019-06-17 14:57:19] cat ~/.bash_myhistory 
2  [2019-06-17 15:03:12] history -n
```

Huh... none of `echo` commands are read. Switch to second terminal again and:

```
$ echo "Z"
$ history -w
```

Now the history file is:

```
#1560772821
echo "X"
#1560772823
echo "Y"
#1560773057
echo "Z"
```

Switch to first terminal again:

```
$ history -n
$ history
  1  [2019-06-17 14:57:19] cat ~/.bash_myhistory 
  2  [2019-06-17 15:03:12] history -n
echo "Z"
```

You can see that `echo "Z"` command is merged to `history -n`.

Another **bug** is because of commands are read from the history by command number and not by command time, I think. I expect others `echo` commands appeared at the history

Answer (score 1):

I went with a combination of answers here:

- I want my history merged at the end, so I used the trap function.
- I also want my history files separated by hosts so I changed HISTFILE to point to a directory and named files depending on hostname.
- I added ignorespace option so I can type clear text passwords and not have them show up on the history, e.g.: `$ ./.secretfunction -user myuser -password mypassword` will not be saved because it starts with space.
- I added `history*` and `exit` to HISTIGNORE just to keep those commands including anything past history like `history | grep awesomecommand` out of there since I normally wouldnt want it. You can add others like: logout, fg, bg, etc.
- I then put it all in my ~/.bash_aliases file so it's not conflicting on upgrades as it has happened sometimes.

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups:ignorespace
HISTIGNORE="history*:exit"
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history/.$(hostname)_history
shopt -s histappend
function historymerge {
    history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r;
}
trap historymerge EXIT
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Grep your ~/ for PROMPT_COMMAND to make sure you arent already getting it modified with history -a.
I also added the TIME/DATE format `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%x %r %Z "` I liked but didnt include in the above block since that is locale sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot of solutions either do not handle history timestamps,  multi-line history entries, or just leave the history a mess, without any nice ordering.

My solution was to first turn on $HISTTIMEFORMAT  (only needs to be set, can be the emtry string if you don't like seeing the timestamps). And then merge the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Optionally removing unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

This is the result... https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

I call this either on demand via and alias ('hc' for history clean) and from the ".bash_logout" profile on shell exit.

Adjust as you like to suit your need.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another combination of the previous answers.

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILESIZE=20000
HISTCONTROL="ignoreboth:erasedups"
HISTIGNORE="history:exit"
function historyclean {
    if [[ -e "$HISTFILE" ]]; then
        exec {history_lock}<"$HISTFILE" && flock -x $history_lock
        history -a
        tac "$HISTFILE" | awk '!x[$0]++' | tac > "$HISTFILE.tmp$$"
        mv -f "$HISTFILE.tmp$$" "$HISTFILE"
        history -c
        history -r
        flock -u $history_lock && unset history_lock
    fi  
}
function historymerge {
    history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; 
}
trap historymerge EXIT

PROMPT_COMMAND="historyclean;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Compared to previous answers:

- historymerge() does not remove or prevent duplicates; but it's useful with trap not to loose history
- use of /tmp is not secure

Reused ideas: lock file, trap on exit, remove duplicates, merge order. Credits to [rozcietrzewiacz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9382/rozcietrzewiacz), [honoredmule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44015/honoredmule), [anthony](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/68648/anthony) and [tony-j](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/430995/tony-j).

Answer (score 0):

erasedups does not trim (like chomp in some languages) the leading and trailing spaces. This is a bug. Also erasedups does not delete all previous entries.

Comment: You can set `HISTIGNORE` to ignore specific commands or when they match certain regexes, `HISTIGNORE=" *:ls:ll:cd:cd -:history:history -*:man:man *:pwd:exit:date:* --help:"` and if you use `ignorespace` you won't have any proceeding whitespace saved on commands anyways.