# How can I repeat the last command in shell without filling up history?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, osx, command-history

I'm working on a project that requires compilation for each test run.  Every time I want to test it out again I press `Up` to get the last command and `Enter` to run it.  The issue is that it fills my History up, so if I want to use a command from before I started a coding session, it's completely buryed in hundreds of the same exact command.

**How can I run a command without it filling up my History?**

And if there isn't a way to do that, is there some way to skip over repeats when going back in History?

I am not totally certain what shell I am using. I am running Terminal, on OSX.  But I would like the answer for as many different shells as is known, because that would make this question more valuable for others later.

```
$ echo $0
-bash
```

EDIT: After a short discussion in comments and some additions to the original text of the question, better search results have appeared in the sidebar, showing this is a duplicate of [How to stop Bash appending history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20747/how-to-stop-bash-appending-history?rq=1).  I'll be marking it as so and closing it.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash?

Comment: Or do you want all of the different answers for the various different shells?

Comment: Not totally certain.  Terminal in OSX, but as many as you know off the top of your head would make this question more valuable for others later.

Comment: I think OSX defaults to `bash`

Comment: Terminal is a terminal emulator program.  It is _not_ the shell that you are using.  You are _probably_ using the Z Shell, possibly a heavily customized one.  But you might not be.  Start with `echo $0` and do not put this stuff in comments.  [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Something I don't see mentioned in this or the linked answer is simply adding a space as the first character of your command, which will prevent it from being inserted in `.bash_history`.  So, you can just type a space followed by `!!` to rerun the previous command without an additional entry in the history.

Comment: I know you're an op but I don't think it's a duplicate. Your question has a very direct answer: ` !!` (that is "space bang bang") - space prevents adding to history and double bang repeats last command.