# Remove duplicate lines from a file but leave 1 occurrence

Tags: linux, text-processing

I'm looking to remove duplicate lines from a file but leave 1 occurrence in the file.

**Example of the file:**

```
this is a string
test line
test line 2
this is a string
```

From the above example, I would want to remove 1 occurrence of "this is a string".

Best way to do this?

Comment: With such questions you should always provide example input and output.

Comment: Possibly related: [Remove duplicate lines while keeping the order of the lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194780/remove-duplicate-lines-while-keeping-the-order-of-the-lines)

Comment: Are the duplicated lines adjacent to one another? Is the output to remain in the same order or would it be ok to sort the data?

Comment: Keep one occurrence of a duplicate (ie two identical lines per match) or simply "remove all duplicate lines, leaving only one line per set of duplicates"? Does the final order matter?

Comment: I thought it was fairly overt but I have added an example, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: it is not a problem for you that the lines will be sorted, then a `sort file|uniq` will do what you want.

Comment: @peterh that isn't doing anything, it just prints out to the console and doesn't make any changes.

Comment: @TomBailey Believe me, it should work. Try it with a minimal text file what you've typed it manually, and you will see that it works.

Comment: @peterh ahhh yeah so I just append the output from that to a new file. Yeah that's works, thank you.

Answer (score 15):

### Demo file `stuff.txt` contains:

```
one
two
three
one
two
four
five
```

**Remove duplicate lines from a file assuming you don't mind that lines are sorted**

```
$ sort -u stuff.txt 
five
four
one
three
two
```

Explanation: the u flag sent to sort says sort the lines of the file and force unique.

**Remove duplicate lines from a file, preserve original ordering, keep the first:**

```
$ cat -n stuff.txt | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2-
one
two
three
four
five
```

Explanation: The n flag passed to cat appends line numbers to left of every line, plus space, then the first sort says sort by unique and but only after the first word, the second sort command says use the line numbers we stored in step 1 to resort by the original ordering, finally cut off the first word.

**Remove duplicate lines from a file, preserve order, keep last.**

```
tac stuff.txt > stuff2.txt; cat -n stuff2.txt | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- > stuff3.txt; tac stuff3.txt > stuff4.txt; cat stuff4.txt
three
one
two
four
five
```

Explanation: Same as before, but tac reverse the file, achieving the desired result.

Comment: > Remove duplicate lines from a file, preserve original ordering, keep the first:
`cat -n stuff.txt | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2-`

The command you gave doesn't preserve at least one occurrence. I tested it out with a file which contained only duplicates, and only the last line remained after running the command (because it contained a newline, and was therefore unique)

Comment: Surprise left jab: Whitespace and newlines at end of file, relative to end of lines, are both different and significant.  I diagnose your operating system as defective.  Bazinga.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to edit my previous comment, but slight correction - the last line is the only line that **didn't** contain a newline, and was therefore unique. 



I used Ilya Bobyr's solution below, which worked fine and preserved one occurrence, as required. The problem with your solution was that if there were two non-unique entries, then **neither** of them was preserved.

Answer (score 7):

As removing all but the last occurrence is the inverse of removing all but the first, there is also this solution:

```
tac file | awk '! seen[$0]++' | tac
```

`tac` reverses lines in the file, and `awk` will only output the first occurrence of a duplicate line.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments you want the result to be the same output file without having to create another output or append into the new file, you could use the following:

example:

```
gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' $file
```

Answer (score 2):

This leaves the first occurrence:

```
awk '! a[$0]++' inputfile

start cmd:> echo 'this is a string
cont. cmd:> test line
cont. cmd:> test line 2
cont. cmd:> this is a string' | awk '! a[$0]++'
    this is a string
    test line
    test line 2
```

Comment: It seems to just print out and not actually make in changes in the file.

Comment: @TomBailey That's why I told you to provide example input and output. I did test it and it works fine for me.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Comment: @TomBailey works fine for me.

Comment: See my answer without creating another output to store the result

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim, could try the following code:

```
g/./if(temp == getline('.')) | let temp = getline('.') | else | :norm dd | endif
```