# After closing a tab in Gnome terminal, how to retrieve the command history in it?

Tags: bash, command-history, gnome-terminal

When working in several tabs in gnome terminal, if I close one tab, do I lose all the command history in the tab?

In an existing tab, Is there a way to retrieve a previous command typed in a closed tab?

Thanks.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/bash-history-ignoredups-and-erasedups-setting-conflict-with-common-history

Comment: Command history is up to your shell and has nothing to do with the terminal. I see you've tagged the question [tag:bash], so I think you're actually asking this question about Bash not about Gnome Terminal. Short answer is that most installations of Bash are set up to save history by default.

Comment: @Celada It is related to terminal. each gnome terminal tab runs a separate bash process. When you close a terminal tab, you kill its bash process.

Comment: @Tim: correct, but nothing to do with the terminal. When you exit a shell using any other method (such as logging out of an SSH session) the same thing happens.

Comment: ... A nudge toward what I think is the answer you seek... I've ran into this myself. When you open several tabs, each Gnome Terminal tab / bash shell keeps its own history log (they act in a  "compartimentalized" way). History logs are consolidated when you've exited all bash shells opened with tabs. Subsequently when as you reopen your first terminal window, I think you should see a consolidated history of all previously opened tabs.